# Firebase dynamic link redirect always in app store even app is already installed

Tags: swift, iphone, firebase, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

I created firebase dynamic link, and implement in my iOS app. But the link is not redirect in application even while app is already installed. It always reached at AppStore. I tried much to find the solution but can not reached the consolation yet.

What can be the cause of issue, can anyone please help me ?

Or can you please give solution for the issue ?

Comment: Its difficult to identify the error without having info on how it is configured on the console. However, for starters, you may try putting flag `?d=1` at the end of your dynamic URL and open it in any browser to verify whether its has any erroneous pathways.